# python function only works when value is global

Tags: python, scope

when i do

```
def togglesize():
    global is_small
    
    if is_small == True:
        notsmall()
        is_small = not is_small
    elif is_small == False:
        makesmall()
        is_small = not is_small
```

it works, but when i do this

```
def togglesize():
    is_small = True
    
    if is_small == True:
        notsmall()
        is_small = not is_small
    elif is_small == False:
        makesmall()
        is_small = not is_small
```

it doesn't work

why does it only work when global?

Comment: Define "working"?  What are you expecting to have happened that isn't happening?  Note that in your second function, any variable outside the function called `is_small` has no connection to the `is_small` inside the code, and your `is_small = not is_small` pretty much doesn't nothing, since you immediately return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the variable `is_small` outside of the scope of the function, you can pass it as an argument and return its new value. You probably don't need to use a global variable.

```
def togglesize(is_small):
    if is_small == True:
        notsmall()
        is_small = not is_small
    elif is_small == False:
        makesmall()
        is_small = not is_small
    return is_small
```

If you call your function like this:

```
is_small = togglesize(is_small)
```

This will modify `is_small` from True to False or False to True.

Answer (score 1):

With this line
`is_small = True`
you are setting `is_small` to `True` every time you call the function.
This part

```
        notsmall()
        is_small = not is_small
```

gets executed every time you call the function. The rest never runs.

Edit: Also, in your second example `is_small` is discarded when the function ends. So it does not matter what value you set it to. If you want it to persist, you need to make it available outside the function. Adding `global` does that.